# JPA Mapping for lookup information from table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I would like to know how to map the following

I have two Entity classes called Parts and PartType

**Parts**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARTS")
public class Parts

@Id
@Column(name = "PART_ID")
private Long partId;

@Column(name = "PART_NAME")
private String partName;

@Column(name = "PART_TYPE")
private String partType;

// with getters and setters
```

**PartType**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PART_TYPE")
public class PartType

@Id
@Column(name = "PART_TYPE")
private String partType;

@Column(name = "PART_DESC")
private String partType;

@Column(name = "PART_OWNER")
private String partOwner;


// with getters and setters
```

In database there is a relation between `PART_TYPE` of **PARTS** table and `PART_TYPE` of **PART_TYPE** table. It is linked with a foreign key from **PARTS** table to **PART_TYPE**, `PART_TYPE` is the primary key in **PART_TYPE** table.

**PART_TYPE** is a look up table to get the information of a `PART_TYPE`.

What I would like to know is if I would want to map JPA relationship, should I map it has `OnetoOne` mapping or `ManytoOne` mapping from Parts Entity to PartType Entity?

I would want to acheive two things in my application in relation to this, one I would want to get PART_TYPE details like desc, owner etc as one row so that I can display in grid and when user would want to edit the grid information, I would want to display partType and partDesc as a combo drop down.

I am getting into JPA and Hibernate, so any help on this is very much useful

Comment: Use a ManyToOne if several parts can share the same part type, and a OneToOne if a single part can reference a given part type. As simple as that.

Comment: @JBNizet If I use OneToOne mapping, do I need to have a mapping from PartType to Part Entity?

Comment: Every kind of association can be unidirectional or bidirectional. You choose.

Comment: @JBNizet How to clarify ManyToOne and OneToOne in JPA, I am getting confused with these. Thanks

Comment: check out this site, it has some very good examples of association mappings: http://tadtech.blogspot.dk/2007/09/hibernate-association-mappings-in.html

Comment: Hibernate has documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/. It contains examples for all the kinds of associations.

Comment: @EmilKaminski Thanks for providng the link.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the help and for the documenatation.